# Search YouTube from Linux CLI and return URL

Tags: ubuntu

How can I search YouTube from the Linux command line terminal, and return the URL?

I've found [StackExchange: CLI utility to search and view/download YouTube videos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495998/cli-utility-to-search-and-view-download-youtube-videos)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [mps-youtube](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube) where you can search youtube, hope this solves your question.

Comment: How can I get it to return the URL of the Video?

Comment: this is simple after you do a search, please use this command i video_number in the list

Comment: for example you want to search for 'cats' videos, you will write /cats command and after a list is shown in the app use this command 'i video_order_in_the_list' (if you want say the 3rd video in the results list, type i 3)

Comment: I'm guessing I can use the "video id" as the final part of the URL?

Comment: How can I run this from bash script?

Answer (score -2):

`sudo apt-get install mps-youtube`